# decimals issue with pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have Anaconda 3 on windows 10. I am reading csv files with an European format ( ',' as a separator). I use 'decimal' to specify the comma, but it does not apply to all the columns.

The csv file rows are like this :

```
2;PAU;11:21:19;00:00;00:00;0;0;2,102;0,00;20,75;20,75;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00


x=pd.read_csv(file,sep=';',decimal=',',encoding='latin-1',low_memory=False)
```

the output is like this :

```
0 2 PAU 11:21:19 00:00 00:00 0 0 2,102 0.00 20.75 20.75 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

The european format was successfully taken into account for 20.75 but not for 2,102.

Any suggestion?

edit : still no clean solution, i managed by doing this :

```
x['Tension'] = x['Tension'].str.replace(',','.')
```

Comment: Do you have proper headers?

Comment: Here are the headers : Pas;Etat;Heure;Durée pas;Durée programme;Cycle;Niveau du cycle;Tension;Courant;Tempborne+;Temptop;AhCha;AhDch;AhPas;WhAccu;WhCha;WhDch;WhPas;AhAccu

Comment: Have you tried removing encoding='latin-1' ?

Comment: yes, it won't work without it

Comment: For european formatting, I would use [`babel`](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 5):

It happens because your data is interpreted as a header. Read it with mentioning that you have no header:

```
x=pd.read_csv(file,sep=';',decimal=',',
    encoding='latin-1',low_memory=False,header=None)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually there is a header in my dataset. Removing it with header=None does not solve the issue.

Comment: @GillesL Can you show your dataset (or a part of it) here?

Comment: Here are the 3 first lines :


Pas;Etat;Heure;Durée pas;Durée programme;Cycle;Niveau du cycle;Tension;Courant;Tempborne+;Temptop;AhCha;AhDch;AhPas;WhAccu;WhCha;WhDch;WhPas;AhAccu
;;;;;;;[V];[A];[C];[C1];[AhCha];[AhDch];[AhPas];[Wh];[WhCha];[WhDch];[WhPas];[Ah]
2;PAU;11:21:19;00:00;00:00;0;0;2,102;0,00;20,75;20,75;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00

Comment: @GillesL Well, since some columns of your second line do contain textual values, the entire dataframe has values in these columns as text. You can't mix text and numeric values in the same column; if even one value is textual, the rest of this column is interpreted as text. Just remove the second line.

Comment: I tried to open the csv without the headers with skiprows, but the issue is still the same.

Comment: @GillesL Open the file with editor, remove the second line, read the file. Or add `header=['Pas', 'Etat', .......], skiprows=2` in a `read_csv` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone coming from a google search like: *pandas read_csv decimal not working*, might have strings and floats in the same column. In this case pandas cannot apply the `decimal` option.

Have a look into the `na_values` parameter. I had an odd string that denoted NAN values. `na_values` let's you explicitly handle these.